# How to compute $Ext_A^{1}(S_1, S_2)$ and $Ext_A^{1}(S_2, S_1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $A = kQ/\rho $, $Q$ is the quiver
\begin{align}
1 \overset{a}{\underset{a^*}{\rightleftarrows}} 2
\end{align}
$\rho$ is the relation $a a^* - a^* a = 0$. Question: compute $Ext_A^{1}(S_1, S_2)$.

My solution: Since $aa^*$ and $a^*a$ start from different vertices, $\rho$ is the same as $a a^*=0$, $a^* a=0$. We have the following indecomposable modules of $A$:
\begin{align}
S_1 =  \mathbb{C} \overset{0}{\underset{0}{\rightleftarrows}} 0, \quad S_2 =  \mathbb{0} \overset{0}{\underset{0}{\rightleftarrows}} \mathbb{C}, \quad P(1) =  \mathbb{C} \overset{1}{\underset{0}{\rightleftarrows}} \mathbb{C}, \quad P(2) =  \mathbb{C} \overset{0}{\underset{1}{\rightleftarrows}} \mathbb{C}
\end{align}
Let $\dim(M) = (d_i)_{i\in I}$ be the dimension vector of $M$. 
The following exact sequence is a projective resolution of $M$:
\begin{align}
0 \to \bigoplus_{\alpha \in Q_1} d_{s(\alpha)} P(t(\alpha)) \to \bigoplus_{i \in Q_0} d_{i} P(i) \to M \to 0
\end{align} 
For $M=S_2$, we have $\dim(S_1) = (1, 0)$ and an exact sequence
\begin{align}
0 \to  P(2) \to P(1) \to S_1 \to 0
\end{align}
After applying $\hom(S_2, -)$ to the above exact sequence, we obtain a left exact sequence
\begin{align}
0 \to  \hom(S_2, S_1) \to \hom(S_2, P(1)) \overset{f_1}{\to} \hom(S_2, P(2))   \overset{f_2}{\to} 0
\end{align}
I think that $Ext_A^1(S_1, S_2) = \ker(f_2)/im(f_1) = \hom(S_2, P(2))/im(f_1)$. But I don't konw $im(f_1)$.

How to compute $Ext_A^{1}(S_2, S_1)$ and how to show that $Ext_A^{1}(S_1, S_2)=1$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your resolutions are not resolutions: they are not *exact*.

Comment: In fact $A$ has infinite projective dimension, not projective dimension $1$.

Comment: I will just clarify Mariano and Julian's comment for the OP.  The mistake in the calculation is that the ``projective resolution" you quoted works only for module of projective dimension 1.  If you actually calculate the kernel of $P_1\to S_1$, you will see it is $S_2$, so the resulting ses is $0\to S_2\to P_1\to S_1\to 0$.  In particular, the non-zero element of $Ext_A^1(S_1,S_2)$ corresponds to this non-split extension.  If you only want the dimension of the Ext-groups between simples, then all you need to do is to count the number of arrows from one vertex to another -no calculation needed.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much. If we want to compute the dimension of the Ext-groups between simples, what arrows do we need to count?

Comment: $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{Ext}^1(S_i,S_j)=$ number of arrows $i \to j$

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer, thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, in general, whether to count $i\to j$ or $j\to i$ depends on how you define Ext-quiver, or which way you work (i.e. left modules or right modules, and direction of multiplying arrows).  In your example, we see from how you write down $P(1)$ to determine which direction is the correct one.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much.